# How to install node_modules only those packages defined in the file package.json

Tags: node.js, laravel

When I used npm install of Laravel project. It creates a lot of unnecessary libraries.
I want to know how to install only the packages I have defined in package.json file.

[image: Screenshot of node_modules content]

Comment: They're transitive dependencies and you can't get rid of them :|

Answer (score 2):

It is because `npm install` is recursive. Let's say your project require the module `A`, which itself require the module `B`, `npm install` will end up installing both.

In short, even if you only used one module in your `package.json`, all the modules you see *are* needed.

Answer (score 1):

Those packages have dependencies which have dependencies of their own. So unless you want to break your application, I wouldn't alter it.